# Chrome Responsive show different as Firefox

Tags: responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools

sorry for my English...

I do try to write the Media Query for **Samsung SM-J810F Galaxy J8 1480 x 720** .

I write on Media Query;

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 30.8125em) 
               and (device-height: 15em)
               and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
               and ( min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
               and (orientation: landscape)  {
```

Here how to show on Firefox

[image]

Here how to show on Chrome;

[image]

How to see, on Chrome to show the **nav** different..., also to come an **Element** which I will not display it, it displays on Chrome but not on Firefox...

Can please anyone explains my mistake, because display this element on Chrome.

very Thanks for your answer!

Comment: hello, were you able to get a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your media query looks problematic to me because it includes webkit AND mozilla vendor prefixes, so I'm not sure if it will give the results you are expecting.

I have two suggestions you could try.

(1) Rewrite you media query as

```
@media 
only screen and (device-width: 30.8125em) 
               and (device-height: 15em)
               and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
               and (orientation: landscape),

 only screen and (device-width: 30.8125em) 
               and (device-height: 15em)
               and ( min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
               and (orientation: landscape)  {
```

or

(2) Use the more future proof dppx syntax
source   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-device-pixel-ratio

```
@media 
only screen and (device-width: 30.8125em) 
               and (device-height: 15em)
               and (min-resolution: 2dppx) 
               and (orientation: landscape)  {
```

Good luck, I hope one of these suggestions works for you!

Comment: Very Thanks for your recommendation, but both not working on Chrome... here you can show my media query for desktop, tablet and smartphone, https://playcode.io/482138

Comment: Hi, you aren't making life easy for yourself trying to target specific devices ;) This is a bit of a stab in the dark because I'm not sure what I'm looking for but is this any better? https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/wvBrPNm

Comment: Thanks, what recommend you to me to build a Media Query file for desktop, tablet and smartphone ?